# Issues running Blender from the command line despite setting up environmental variables

Tags: error, command-line, windows

I have become interested in running Blender from the command line (Windows) to make my workflow more efficient. I also want to be able to run it directly without pointing Windows to my directory each time. So I have tried adding it to my environmental variables, however despite adding the Blender .exe folder to my user and system variables:
[image]

I still get "'blender' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." in the command prompt:

[image]

Unfortunately all the documentation I can find on setting up a path to Blender in Windows are outdated, and even the official Blender guide just mentions it as a option without describe how to do it. I assume I am missing something basic here but for the life of me I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT ---

Solved! Put the path here instead of making a new variable:
[image]

Comment: Weren't you supposed to be pointing directly to the `.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t create a new blender variable, add the blender folder to the variable PATH.

That’s how I do it, anyway.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly. Thank you! I will put where I put the path in the original post so other users stumbling across this can see as well.

Comment: @CarlChurchill good job. 